# Update the columns in Mysql every year

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, mysqli, sql-update

I would like to update few columns in my database every year. I am using PHP and MYSQL.

How to update/reset the columns to specific values every year ?

I have heard that we use it with the Time stamp.

I have searched a lot about it .. nothing found.

Can someone help me ?

Thanks in Advance :)

EDIT 1 :

I am making an election system for my DBMS project.

This is how my table looks like

[student table in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUTkw.png)

I would like to refresh the register_Check and C_reg_no columns every year !!

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: The syntax for an update in SQL is `UPDATE tableName SET columnName = value;`.  Note that updating a whole column with the same static value indicates a serious problem with your database design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you would restructure your database to handle different values for different years.

Move those columns into another table and a column for year and another as a foreign key field to link the registration info to the user info. 
Then you can keep track of the values for each year.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the result using external script or MySQL Event Scheduler.

PHP - [setup a cron job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php) to run every year

MySQL - [Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-overview.html)

Answer (score -1):

One way is to set up an annual cron job which calls a script to reset the values.